# Makefile compile notification says there is no rule for a target; I cannot see the problem

Tags: c, makefile

I am going through a tutorial on building an operating system. This is new frontier for me. I am using my Android phone to complete the build; I have installed all the technologies I require to implement the project. I have created the bootloader and have been able to print to screen. I have now reached the implementation stage of the *FAT12 file system*. The *Makefile* directs the use of the *clang* compiler; *gcc* is no longer available to me.

My issue is this: having created `tools/fat/fat.c` (*fat.c* just outputs a string to show that the compile works), the rules, targets and prerequisites, the build fails with the notification:

```
make: *** No rule to make target '/fat/fat.c'. needed by 'build/tools/fat'. Stop
```

Debug: up to the `tools` directory, the output is;
`No need to remake target ...`; the last line of the debug output says:
`Must remake target '/fat/fat.c'.`

I have tried to research the issue, but have come up empty-handed. Solutions to similar `No rule...target...` issues are varied, complex and not what I am looking for. To be honest, I have no idea what I am looking for, or how to resolve this issue.

Here is my code;

```
ASM = nasm
CC = clang

SRC_DIR = src
TOOLS_DIR = tools
BUILD_DIR = build

.PHONY all floppy_image kernel bootloader clean always tools_fat

all: floppy_image tools_fat

    ...    # bootloader implementation; works

# tools
tools_fat: $(BUILD_DIR)/tools/fat
$(BUILD_DIR)/tools/fat: always $(TOOLS_DIR)/fat/fat.c
    mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)/tools
    $(CC) $(BUILD_DIR)/tools/fat $(TOOLS_DIR)/tools/fat/fat.c

always:
    mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)

clean:
    rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)/*
```

Where the compiler directive is concerned, the tutorial assumes *gcc* will be used; I had to change to *clang*. So, where *gcc*, `$(CC) -g -o` should be written, I have removed it; I have not provided any *clang* options, as the call to the compiler is meant to be as one would compile on the Command Line.

I do not know what the issue is; I would appreciate some help. Thank you.

Comment: It's acting like `TOOLS_DIR` isn't set. Are you sure you have the assignment `TOOLS_DIR = tools`?

Comment: A separate problem. You need `-o` after `$(CC)`.

Comment: Also, `$(TOOLS_DIR)/tools` is fishy

Comment: `$(TOOLS_DIR)/fat/fat.c` and `$(TOOLS_DIR)/tools/fat/fat.c` don't match.

Comment: @Retired Ninja  @ikegami My apologies; you are correct. The line should read ```$(BUILD_DIR)tools/fat $(TOOLS_DIR)/fat/fat.c```

Comment: @Barmar Your question is what I am unsure of. Though it is written at the top of the file, debug shows that `tools` can't be read; I don't know why.

Comment: @Barmar Issued resolved. I removed `$(TOOLS_DIR) = tools` and replaced all $(TOOLS_DIR) with the directory name `tools`; all working. Thank you, everyone, for your help.